# Term for Giving a Discount for a second time?

Tags: discounting

I have created an invoice where the total service charge comes to 100 USD and a discount of 30 USD adds up making total charges as : 100 - 30 = 70 USD.

Now customer is asking for a further 10 USD discount; 
How to term the second discount in the Invoice as i already have term 'Discount' 30 USD in the invoice.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't it just be called "Discount" again? Or alternatively just put the "Discount" as $40 without breaking it out into $30 and $10?

Comment: I was going to use the same ie Further Discount; was checking if something elseis used by experts in this domain

Comment: Is this for your accounting program?

Comment: "_Additional discount_"? "_Won't-even-pay-the-already-discounted-amount-discount_" :-)

Comment: @RonJohn not for accounting program but to generate an invoice